# OpenSuse stuck at start job and won't finish booting, any advice?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, opensuse, software-updates

My OpenSuse Tumbleweed installation has somehow stopped booting at all. The startup process goes through normally, but then it says `A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (7 min / no limit)` and that's it. No matter how much I wait there seems to be no way for it to finish whatever it's doing. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or any other combination only brings me to the same problem. The only thing that seems to work is the old REISUB key sequence to reboot the whole thing.

As asked here's my hardware configuration:

- ASUS PRIME X370-PRO motherboard with lastest BIOS update
- Ryzen 5 1500X processor running at stock clock speed
- Nvidia GTX 1060 3GB
- Kingston HyperX 2133Mhz 8gb RAM memory

The Nvidia card is running the propietary software, which is working well pre-update (even though it was hard to get it running)

I'm on kernel version 4.15.0-1-default, which gets updated when I run `sudo zypper dup`.

EDIT: I've rolled back my installation to a point before updating the system (using snapper), and it works fine. Then I tried to update again, and it brought me to the same problem. What can I do besides leaving my system outdated?

Comment: could you please precise your hardware configuration, it sounds a lot like a driver or firmware issue. Your kernel version would be lovely as well.

Comment: @Kiwy added it to the question

Comment: "No matter how much I wait there seems to be no way for it to finish whatever it's doing." Can you state how long you actually waited? Because I observed the same problem - admittedly on an older, slower system - that took a *night* in that state to actually recover itself. So in the case after one month you are still at this state I would suggest to give it up to 24h and see if e.g. an automatic btrfs recovery can solve the situation.

Comment: @okurz I tried leaving it for 5 hours, with no result. I have since switched to Arch, when I’m not having such problems.

Comment: FWIW, this service is `plymouth-quit-wait.service`. (Seems weird if ctrl+alt+del doesn't run a clean reboot). This could happen if (giving the example of gnome and gdm), an upgrade to gdm caused it to fail to ever stop plymouth.  When you see this problem you could test adding `plymouth.enable=0` to the kernel boot options.

Answer (score 0):

I had many issues with NVIDIA drivers during system updates, so this might me the case.

What I usually do is to uninstall NVIDIA driver and use e.g. nouveau driver (with which I had no issues during update), then, after successful update, try to install the drivers again.

Answer (score -1):

I had that happen running as a VM; I disabled 3D acceleration and it boots fine now.